# selected value cleared in postback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, postback

I've dynamically bonded select list and when I hit save button then I'm getting value 0 not the selected one.

I'm Using HtmlSelect not Asp:Dropdownlist.

Can anybody help me.?
thanks in advance !!

Comment: post some code please,

Comment: cant help you without seeing the code

Comment: post the code of the place where you are binding the dropdownlist

Comment: are you binding the data again? if yes, put the code which is adding data to the dropdown into «if(!IsPostBack){ //your code }»

Comment: Actually, I'm Binding the data using javascript..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using html select.,
 you use javascript function for change ddl and assign changed ddl value at one hidden field. send that hidden field value to server. Check below code.

```
 function onchangeddl(e) {
               var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlid') 
               for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
                   if (ddl.options[i].text == e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text) {                           
                       ddl.selectedIndex = i;
                       ddl.options[i].selectedValue = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].value;
                       ddl.options[i].selected = true;   

                       document.getElementById('<%=hdnfld.ClientID%>').value = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
                       break;
                   }
               }                 

           }
```

Codebehind.aspx page you have to assign hdnfld value.

I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Thank You so much. this is what I exactly needed